# Cannot read property ... of undefine , at Object.callbackFromNative In angular 2

Tags: javascript, angular, callback

I have a code by flow

```
declare var Speech: any;
    export class Lesson implements OnInit {
       text = '';
       constructor()
{
this.text = 'hh';
}
ToSpeech(){
  Speech.listen(this.listenSucess);
}
listenSucess(result){
this.text = reuslt;
}
```

file Speech.js

```
var Speech= (function () {
return {
   listen:funtion(sucess){
      window.plugins.speechRecognition.startListening(function (result) {
          success(result);
      }
   }
}
```

and I have an error like :

```
Cannot read property 'this.text' of undefined 
at Object.callbackFromNative
```

I used callback for this funtion, Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Did you try fat arrow `=>` instead of `function`? Because `this` is not accessible inside a `function`

```
var Speech = (() => {
return {
   listen = (success) => {
      window.plugins.speechRecognition.startListening((result) => {
          success(result);
      }
   }
}
```